# get the current lang in xslt

Tags: sharepoint-server, xslt, localization, refinement-panel

I'm new with XSLT and have a WebPart refiner.
In the XSLT, i've the param at the beginning: CurrentLcid

```
<xsl:param name="CurrentLcid"></xsl:param>
```

When i test the value, the value is always 2060 if i change language from my account shortcut in top right, the value stays at 2060

Do you have a solution on how to get the current language?